# adding js and css files to the page Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How do I add the js file to my page?

I have the following structure:

```
public
 - css
 - js
 - vendor
   - bootstrap
   - jquery
```

I want to use the jquery and bootstrap that are in my vendor folder.

I'm trying the following way.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=" {{ asset('vendor/jquery/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js) }} "> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=" {{ asset('vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js) }} " > </script>
```

but does not work, error appears

```
syntax error, unexpected 'vendor' (T_STRING)
```

Comment: You are missing the closing quote in asset('vendor/jquery/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js). Right after .js

Answer (score 1):

you have forgot to put `'` at the end of assert function

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('vendor/jquery/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js')}}"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"> </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You are missing the closing quote:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=" {{ asset('vendor/jquery/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js') }} "> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=" {{ asset('vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js') }} " > </script>
```